# Read multiple csv files with first 5 rows in 5 minutes in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple CSV files on /root/*.csv location and want to print first 5 rows in every 5 minutes of interval from all files. After next 5 minutes it will again read next 5 rows from all the CSV files.

Tried with below python code but it just print all the rows from all CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import glob
import os

# Import CSV
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob('*.csv')))
print(df)
```

Please help me for the ask.

f1.csv
Name,City,Country
AB,Pune,India
CD,Pune,India
EF,Pune,India
GH,Pune,India
IJ,Pune,India
KL,Pune,India
MN,Pune,India

f2.csv
Name,City,Country
Bob,Nsk,India
Pop,Nsk,India
Mom,Nsk,India
Cop,Nsk,India
Lop,Nsk,India
Sop,Nsk,India

Comment: *in every 5 minutes of interval* - what about this requirement, have you implemented it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import time

csv_files = glob.glob('/root/*.csv') 
skip=0
while True:
    for file in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=skip, nrows=5)   file
        print(df)
        skip+=5
    time.sleep(300)  # Pause execution for 5 minutes (300 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks @zoldxk. It's working correctly for first iteration i.e. it reads first 5 rows from all the CSV files but in the second iteration it again reads same first 5 rows. Here in the second iteration, it should skip first 5 rows and consider next 5 rows.

Comment: I made some edits to my code, check it

Comment: Tried with updated code and to avoid comment space kept **nrows=2, skip+=2**   

By running script, it skips row **AB from f1.csv & Mom from f2.csv**.

I have updated f1.csv and f2.csv in my initial question.